# Why is "Hope and Despair" (希望と絶望) such a common theme?

Tags: tropes, japanese-language

It seems to be popular in a lot of Japanese writing, actually. The exact words 希望 and 絶望 are very common. Just look at Danganronpa. Anyone know the origins of such a theme, specifically of the specific words and why they have such relevance in Japanese fiction? The words are paired together in a set every single time without fail. Even in today's Shuumatsu no Valkyrie episodes I saw it come up. It was in a Black Clover chapter as well. I'm sure I could come up with dozens if not hundreds of examples given a few hours.

Comment: The basis of this question is formed from selective bias, anime, manga, novel games, and related novels are but a small niche Japanese literature and not a good representation of archetypes of themes. Certain anime and manga genres are built upon on certain archetypes and cliches, but that does not preclude those stories to those niches. It's all up to the writers, directors and/or artists/illustrators and how they engage their audience through their medium.

Answer (score 0):

Hope and despair is just the set theme in general. as far as I'm aware theres no real reason its just what danganronppa is set around. If junko wants despair than someone will want hope, Its just what makes it interesting. same with how **spoilers?** V3 is set around lies and truth.